# how do I manage 2 version of ionic on windows

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I know recently Ionic has released it's latest version in beta Ionic 2. But I was already using the older version for my project. I want to try Ionic 2 before I can migrate my app to Ionic 2. So is there a way I can keep 2 versions of Ionic at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we've stated in the docs, [link here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/installation/)

> Worried about your V1 Ionic projects? Don’t worry! The beta release has all the functionality to work with both V1 projects and V2 projects.

You can have the beta CLI installed and still use the V1 commands.

Answer (score 0):

one way is to locally put the src of ionic in a custom folder and refer to it (by alias or symlink) to include it in your project.